# Cascade not working as I expect

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, cascade, fluent, cascading-deletes

I'm relatively new to configuring NHibernate and have run in to a problem. I have the following entities :

```
public class Report
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Path { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Alias { get; private set;}

    public virtual IList<Tab> Tabs
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}

public class Tab
{
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public virtual Report ParentReport { get; private set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I use Fluent NHibernate and Auto Mapping to map the relationships.

```
.Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ShowSql().ConnectionString(c => c.Is(connectionString)))                
.Mappings(map => map.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Workbook>(configuration)
.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CascadeAll>()
```

The problem is that not matter what cascade options I choose in my CascadeAll class I can't get it to perform as I'd wish which is.

When I remove a Tab from a given report, I want the sections on the tab to be removed from the database, and then the tab to be removed from the report in the database.

```
Cascade.All()
```

Removes the relationship between Report and Tab, but orphans the tab setting ParentReport_id to equal null.

```
Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
```

This removes all sections, tabs associated with the report, and then deletes the report, despite only removing one tab from the collection on the report.

```
Cascade.SaveUpdate()
```

Acts like All in that it orhpans the tab.

Incidentally these are all invoked by removing a tab from the tab collection on Report and then calling session.SaveUpdate(instance) > Where instance is the Report instance being updated.

Any idea how I can remedy this or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your classes that implement IHasManyConvention and IReferenceConvention.

Comment: @p.petkov 'public class CascadeAll : IHasOneConvention, IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.All();
        }

        public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.All();
        }

        public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Cascade.Delete();
        }
    }'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Rex, I suspect that your suggestion would work so time allowing I may give it a try. It was completely down to the relationship between Report and Tab, causing  a OneToMany (Report-> Tab) and a ManyToOne (Tab -> Report). With the cascade options I chose it would either NUll the foreign key, or remove the tab, all other tabs and the report. This was with the AllDeleteOrphan.

When I remove the Tab -> Report ManyToOne relationship the orphan record got deleted fine without the Repotr being removed. In the end I went for a quick option of creating an explicit mapping file which used the HasMany(x => x.Tabs).... in the ReportMapping file & References(x => x.ParentReport)... on TabMapping.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a combination of these. You can write [overrides](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Overrides) for the special cases when you need something other than the default provided by your conventions.

If there's a pattern that comes up in your overrides that holds true a majority of the time, you can create a new convention to handle it, instead of having to specify overrides each time it  happens.

I believe you'll want to use `.AllDeleteOrphan()` for your `Sections` collection, and use `.All()` for your `Tabs` collection.

In your case, I believe your override would look something like this.

```
public class ReportMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Report>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Report> mapping)
    {
        // You don't need this, but I'll leave it for an example...
        //mapping.HasMany(x => x.Tabs).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class TabMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Tab>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Tab> mapping)
    {
        // You don't need this, but I'll leave it for an example...
        //mapping.HasMany(x => x.Sections).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        // This should prevent deletes from being cascaded to the Report
        //   (which would delete the report).
        mapping.References(x => x.ParentReport).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

To use the overrides, your config would change a bit to look something like this.

```
.Mappings(map => map.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Workbook>(configuration).UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<ReportMappingOverride>()
```

Having the property back to the parent report shouldn't matter, but for testing you could take it out and see if that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, I need multiple convention classes attached to each entity? I think I've seen an example somewhere, but can't remember where, don't suppose you have a link?

Comment: Also, I'm presuming that this has nothing to do with the fact that Tab has a reference back to Report?

Comment: @user287079 I've updated my answer to include some code examples on how to do it. I also added a link with more information about overrides.

Comment: @user287079 I think I've completely misunderstood your question. You're right, I think it has everything to do with that ParentReport property. I'm updating my answer again, which should help you out.